# using jquery to alert based on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$( document ).ready(){

const filePath = window.top.$('#FilePath').val();
if ("#FilePath:contains('content')") {
  alert("content is here")

}

)};
```

```html
<div id="filePath">content</div>
```

This is probably really easy but I am trying to alert a message if the filepath div contains a specific word. I looked at various setups and this was the closest I can get, please inform me on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several errors,

- syntax on braces and parenthesis
- case FilePath on the id - must match the markup
- div does not have `.val()` but does have `.text()`
- use the recommended document ready `$(function() {` form
- get that value (text) and see if it includes a value https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

```js
$(function() {
  const filePath = $('#filePath').text();
  if (filePath.includes('content')) {
    alert("content is here");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filePath">content</div>
```